# LINQ: Group by index and value

Tags: c#, linq, c#-7.2

Lets say I have an list of strings with the following values:

> ["a","a","b","a","a","a","c","c"]

I want to execute a linq query that will group into 4 groups:

> Group 1: ["a","a"] Group 2: ["b"] Group 3: ["a","a","a"] Group 4:
>   ["c","c"]

Basically I want to create 2 different groups for the value "a" because they are not coming from the same "index sequence".

Anyone has a LINQ solution for this?

Comment: [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) has `GroupAdjacent`, which seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't understand the output you provided. As I read your question, it seems to me that you want `Group 1: ["a","a"] Group 2: ["b"] Group 3: ["a","a", "a"] Group 4: ["c","c"]`, is that right ?

Comment: Thanks @MarcinJuraszek. Im looking for something without additional libraries... Anyway, it can help if I dive into the repo code

Comment: @Pac0 you are right. I fixed the question

Comment: You can just iterate through your array with `foreach` and build a new data structure (perhaps, `List<string>[]`) with these requirements.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I am looking for a LINQ solution

Comment: The fun here is the logic hehe

Comment: What you want is grouping based on what the next element is which is very anti-LINQ and will probably require buffering somewhere.

Comment: @juanora pure LINQ solution (with built-in LINQ methods) will be ugly, much less readable, and probably less efficient, than a simple foreach. There is just no point in using LINQ here. If you need a LINQ solution, then write your own LINQ extension (for example, `IEnumerable<List<T>> GroupAdjacent(this IEnumerable<T> source)`) method with `foreach` and use it :)

Comment: @juanora just use a foreach, if you try to do this in LINQ it will very complex and hard to read.  There is literally nothing wrong with using a foreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need key other than items of array

```
var x = new string[] { "a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "c" };


int groupId = -1;
var result = x.Select((s, i) => new
{
    value = s,
    groupId = (i > 0 && x[i - 1] == s) ? groupId : ++groupId
}).GroupBy(u => new { groupId });


foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
    foreach (var inner in item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" => " + inner.value);
    }
}
```

Here is the result: [Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EHyXCh)

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the "index sequence" first, then do your group.

```
private class IndexedData
{
    public int Sequence;
    public string Text;
} 

string[] data = [ "a", "a", "b" ... ]

// Calculate "index sequence" for each data element.
List<IndexedData> indexes = new List<IndexedData>();

foreach (string s in data)
{
    IndexedData last = indexes.LastOrDefault() ?? new IndexedData();

    indexes.Add(new IndexedData
    {
        Text = s,
        Sequence = (last.Text == s
                      ? last.Sequence 
                      : last.Sequence + 1)
    });
}

// Group by "index sequence"
var grouped = indexes.GroupBy(i => i.Sequence)
                     .Select(g => g.Select(i => i.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a naive `foreach` implementation where whole dataset ends up in memory (probably not an issue for you since you do `GroupBy`):

```
public static IEnumerable<List<string>> Split(IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    var result = new List<List<string>>();
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        var currentGroup = result.LastOrDefault();
        if (currentGroup?.FirstOrDefault()?.Equals(value) == true)
        {
            currentGroup.Add(value);
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(new List<string> { value });
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here comes a slightly complicated implementation with `foreach` and `yield return` enumerator state machine which keeps only current group in memory - this is probably how this would be implemented on framework level:

EDIT: This is apparently also the way MoreLINQ does it.

```
public static IEnumerable<List<string>> Split(IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    var currentValue = default(string);
    var group = (List<string>)null;

    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        if (group == null)
        {
            currentValue = value;
            group = new List<string> { value };
        }
        else if (currentValue.Equals(value))
        {
            group.Add(value);
        }
        else
        {
            yield return group;
            currentValue = value;
            group = new List<string> { value };
        }
    }

    if (group != null)
    {
        yield return group;
    }
}
```

And this is a joke version using LINQ only, it is basically the same as the first one but is slightly harder to understand (especially since `Aggregate` is not the most frequently used LINQ method):

```
public static IEnumerable<List<string>> Split(IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    return values.Aggregate(
        new List<List<string>>(),
        (lists, str) =>
        {
            var currentGroup = lists.LastOrDefault();
            if (currentGroup?.FirstOrDefault()?.Equals(str) == true)
            {
                currentGroup.Add(str);
            }
            else
            {
                lists.Add(new List<string> { str });
            }

            return lists;
        },
        lists => lists);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an extension method based on the APL scan operator, that is like `Aggregate` but returns intermediate results paired with source values:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, T>> ScanPair<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, TKey seedKey, Func<KeyValuePair<TKey, T>, T, TKey> combine) {
    using (var srce = src.GetEnumerator()) {
        if (srce.MoveNext()) {
            var prevkv = new KeyValuePair<TKey, T>(seedKey, srce.Current);

            while (srce.MoveNext()) {
                yield return prevkv;
                prevkv = new KeyValuePair<TKey, T>(combine(prevkv, srce.Current), srce.Current);
            }
            yield return prevkv;
        }
    }
}
```

You can create extension methods for grouping by consistent runs:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, TResult>> GroupByRuns<TElement, TKey, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TElement> src, Func<TElement, TKey> key, Func<TElement, TResult> result, IEqualityComparer<TKey> cmp = null) {
    cmp = cmp ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
    return src.ScanPair(0,
                        (kvp, cur) => cmp.Equals(key(kvp.Value), key(cur)) ? kvp.Key : kvp.Key + 1)
              .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => result(kvp.Value));
}

public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, TElement>> GroupByRuns<TElement, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TElement> src, Func<TElement, TKey> key) => src.GroupByRuns(key, e => e);
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, TElement>> GroupByRuns<TElement>(this IEnumerable<TElement> src) => src.GroupByRuns(e => e, e => e);

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TResult>> Runs<TElement, TKey, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TElement> src, Func<TElement, TKey> key, Func<TElement, TResult> result, IEqualityComparer<TKey> cmp = null) =>
    src.GroupByRuns(key, result).Select(g => g.Select(s => s));
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TElement>> Runs<TElement, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TElement> src, Func<TElement, TKey> key) => src.Runs(key, e => e);
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TElement>> Runs<TElement>(this IEnumerable<TElement> src) => src.Runs(e => e, e => e);
```

And using the simplest version, you can get either an `IEnumerable<IGrouping>>`:

```
var ans1 = src.GroupByRuns();
```

Or a version that dumps the `IGrouping` (and its `Key`) for an `IEnumerable`:

```
var ans2 = src.Runs();
```