# Is there a Linq equivalent to the unix command uniq

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, uniq

Every search I make assumes "Distinct()", but this is NOT my requirement. I just wish to remove all the repeats. Are there any options using linq (i.e. the Enumerable extensions) ?

For example (in C#)

```
int[] input = new [] {1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,5,4,4,3,2,1,6};

int[] expected = new [] {1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1,6};
```

Comment: So you only want to remove consecutive numbers that are the same?  Then a normal for loop would be faster than linq

Comment: Uhm.  Nope.  Linq works on sets/lists.  So to do what you want you would need to first break your set into many sets - at whatever boundaries you choose, then you could use linq to remove duplicates within each of the smaller sets.. then recombine.

Comment: LINQ is similar to *SQL*, not shell commands. You aren't asking about *unique* entries either, you'r asking about non-repeating entries. There are many ways you can do this, eg by *grouping* on the item itself, or creating an iterator that yields only the first time an item is encountered

Comment: BTW why do you want this? There may be better options, eg ReactiveX is better at handling sequences of events and already contains operators for debouncing, windowing etc. It already has a [DistinctUntilChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229494(v=vs.103).aspx) LINQ operator

Comment: I would suggest starting with `GroupAdjacent` - https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#groupadjacent

Comment: It's similar to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302490/linq-group-by-index-and-value/49314534#49314534)

Comment: Many thanks - in the end I wrote something similar to @PanagiotisKanavos Update 2 after realising that Value Types could cause a problem as mentioned in several places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for non-repeating elements, not unique elements. LINQ-to-Objects operations are essentially iterators. You could write your own iterator method that only yields the first time an item is encountered, eg:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> DistinctUntilChanged(this IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    int? previous=null;
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        if (item!=previous)
        {
            previous=item;
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}

var input = new [] {1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,5,4,4,3,2,1,6};
var result=input.DistinctUntilChanged().ToArray();
```

The result will be :

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1,6};
```

**UPDATE**

Another option is to use [Observable.DistinctUntilChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229494(v=vs.103).aspx) from the System.Reactive Library, eg:

```
var input = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6 };
var result = input.ToObservable()
                  .DistinctUntilChanged()
                  .ToEnumerable()
                  .ToArray();
```

System.Reactive, and Reactive Extensions are meant to handle sequences of events using the basic LINQ operators and more. It's easy to convert between Observable and Enumerable though, with `ToObservable()` and `ToEnumerable()`, so they can be used to handle any collection. After all, an event sequence is similar to an "infinite" sequence

**UPDATE 2**

In case there's any confusion about the use of `int?` to store the previous number, it's to allow easy comparison even with the *first* element of the source without actually calling `First()` on it. If it was ,eg `int previous=0;` and the first element was 0, the comparison would filter out the first element.

By using an `int?` in C# or an `int option` in F# or a `Maybe<int>` if we have a Maybe monad we can differentiate between no initial value and an initial value of 0.

Observable.DistinctUntilChanged uses a flag to check whether we are checking the first element. The equivalent code would be:

```
    public static IEnumerable<int> NonRepeating(this IEnumerable<int> source)
    {
        int previous =0;
        bool isAssigned=false;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (!isAssigned || item != previous)
            {
                isAssigned = true;
                previous = item;
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```

**MoreLINQ**

Finally, one can use the GroupAdjacent method from the [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) library to group repeating items together. Each group contains the repeating source elements. In this particular case though we only need the key values:

```
var result = input.GroupAdjacent(i => i).Select(i => i.Key).ToArray();
```

The nice thing about `GroupAdjacent` is that the elements can be transformed while grouping, eg :

```
input.GroupAdjacent(i => i,i=>$"Number {i}")
```

would return groupings of strings.

Comment: why `int?` instead of `int`?

Comment: What would happen if the first number was 0?

Comment: 0 is still a valid number

Comment: @SimonPrice. Yes. Which means it can't be used as a "missing" value to compare with the first element in the IEnumerable

Comment: in response to your point, 'what would happen if the first number was 0' it wouldnt be an issue because its still a valid integral number only if a null was passed in would this be needed, that should have been your question. but then thats for the OP to handle earlier in his code to make sure there are no nulls in the array

Comment: @SimonPrice you misunderstood the problem. You can't *compare* with `previous` if the first number is a 0. What would you use as the initial `previous` value? 0, -1, int.MinValue? They are all valid numbers. You need either a type that accepts null or a flag. BTW [Observable.DistinctUntilChanged](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/83710cfa9395355af6eb908f96261ea632a49009/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable/DistinctUntilChanged.cs) works with a flag

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with linq, although for performance and readability a simple for loop would probably be the better option.

```
int[] input = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6 };
var result = input.Where((x, i) => i == 0 || x != input[i - 1]).ToArray();
```

Comment: A loop would perform the same action *this* code performs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you're right a loop would have done the job also, but what the OP has asked for is the LINQ in order to perform this action.  I have still however upvoted your answer as that is also technically correct, but this is the best answer

Comment: @SimonPrice no, because both use LINQ. LINQ to Objects operations are just *iterators*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Im not going to get into an argument with you, you're answer despite being technically correct and giving an answer and a way to do it, does not meet the needs of the OP

Comment: @SimonPrice you misunderstand what LINQ is I'm afraid. [This is the source for Where](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,500). It returns an iterator. You can also write an iterator with a method that returns an `IEnumerable<T>` and uses `yield`

Comment: This will only work with lists and arrays while LINQ works with any IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: If you want this to work with `IEnumerable<T>` consider using MoreLINQ's `Lead` or `Lag` rather than `input[i - 1]`.